# How do I get a launcher in Unity to start an app with a particular command argument?

Tags: unity, launcher, google-chrome

Is there any way to make a launcher in Unity start a particular application with a particular command line argument?

So, let's say I've got this application in Unity, `AppFoo`, that I could start from the command line like this:

```
$ appfoo
```

But what if I want to start AppFoo with some command line argument, like `--do-something-cool`?  Just as an example, like this:

```
$ appfoo --do-something-cool
```

More specifically, I want to start Chrome with `--disable-accelerated-compositing` due to [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Pri%20Mstone%20ReleaseBlock%20OS%20Area%20Feature%20Status%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=164555).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way of doing this would probably be by using the app called "Alacarte".

Alacarte is a menu editing applications which is available for free download in the Ubuntu software center.

When the app is installed you can launch it by searching "alacarte" in the dash.

Inside the app you navigate to the app category and then edit the specific app you want by clicking "Properties".

There is a field called "Command" which you from here can edit like your example.

Comment: That worked. I should note that if there is a launcher icon in there before using Alacarte that it needs to be unlocked from there first, and then recreated and locked.